# How do I send params with Uploadify?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, uploadify, swfupload

I'm trying to replace SWFUpload in Wordpress with Uploadify, because it's seems more customize friendly and easier to work with.

Now, I've understand that Wordpress sends some data for a server validation when uploading files. I'm curious how I can use this data in my Uploadify form, to replace Wordpress' own upload form.

This is an example of an upload form from Wordpress:

```
<object width="132" height="23" class="swfupload" data="http://xxx.com/wp-includes/js/swfupload/swfupload.swf?preventswfcaching=1300750794560" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="SWFUpload_0">
<param value="window" name="wmode">
<param value="http://xxx.com/wp-includes/js/swfupload/swfupload.swf?preventswfcaching=1300750794560" name="movie">
<param value="high" name="quality">
<param value="false" name="menu">
<param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
<param value="movieName=SWFUpload_0&amp;uploadURL=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fasync-upload.php&amp;useQueryString=false&amp;requeueOnError=false&amp;httpSuccess=&amp;assumeSuccessTimeout=0&amp;params=post_id%3D3562%26amp%3Bauth_cookie%3Dadmin%257C1301439526%257C5e5e63158e880597c782656a719f1738%26amp%3Blogged_in_cookie%3Dadmin%257C1301439526%257Ce01206ec12b5cee4a605f9abff385cc0%26amp%3B_wpnonce%3Dc52b08b0ce%26amp%3Btype%3Dimage%26amp%3Btab%3Dtype%26amp%3Bshort%3D1&amp;filePostName=async-upload&amp;fileTypes=*.*&amp;fileTypesDescription=All%20Files&amp;fileSizeLimit=4194304b&amp;fileUploadLimit=0&amp;fileQueueLimit=0&amp;debugEnabled=false&amp;buttonImageURL=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.com%2Fwp-includes%2Fimages%2Fupload.png%3Fver%3D20100531&amp;buttonWidth=132&amp;buttonHeight=23&amp;buttonText=%3Cspan%20class%3D%22button%22%3ESelect%20Files%3C%2Fspan%3E&amp;buttonTextTopPadding=3&amp;buttonTextLeftPadding=0&amp;buttonTextStyle=.button%20%7B%20text-align%3A%20center%3B%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%20font-family%3A%22Lucida%20Grande%22%2CVerdana%2CArial%2C%22Bitstream%20Vera%20Sans%22%2Csans-serif%3B%20font-size%3A%2011px%3B%20text-shadow%3A%200%201px%200%20%23FFFFFF%3B%20color%3A%23464646%3B%20%7D&amp;buttonAction=-110&amp;buttonDisabled=false&amp;buttonCursor=-1" name="flashvars">
</object>
```

Now, I'm guessing this form data gets generated here:
http://pastie.org/private/dxuytcqhu7b9odfhkwug
(Entire code here: http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-admin/includes/media.php.source.html begins around line 1494)

But besides that I'm pretty clueless. 
How do I send the needed params through Uploadify? Scriptdata? Which params are needed? Is this even possible?

Comment: Just so you know.. Uploadify actually uses SWFUpload under the hood as of version 3.0.

Comment: Also, you should use Plupload instead.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wplupload/

Comment: Care to tell why Plupload is better? I've seen that particular plugin, and for one I think it's ugly (the reason I wanna replace Wordpress own form is because it's so cluttered and ugly looking)

Comment: It supports drag & drop and file upload "chunking" (which can be more efficient with large documents. -  What is cluttered and ugly about this?: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wplupload/screenshots/

Comment: Might give it a try some other time, for now I think it's visually too similar to Wordpress own upload form, and because of that I see no real use of using it (even though I get that it works heaps better than Wordpress' own)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[scriptData](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/scriptdata/)** option in the configuration. In the example below, there are two parameters being sentm `name` and `age`

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
  'uploader'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
  'script'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
  'cancelImg'   : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
  'folder'      : '/uploads',
  'scriptData'  : {'name':'Ronnie','age':30}
});
```

Comment: Right, so based on this, I only need to send
'scriptData'  : {'movie':'http://xxx.com/wp-includes/js/swfupload/swfupload.swf?preventswfcaching=1300750794560'} and it should pass along the data just like SWFUpload does?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish that may be correct.